# Calling Cocoon, via AJAX, from Apache violates same-origin policy

Tags: ajax, jsonp, apache-cocoon

I've read several posts on AJAX/JSONP, and I can successfully retrieve JSONP data from a Yahoo! API via an AJAX call in a page served on localhost, but I can't get data from Cocoon on localhost.

I have a web page served from Apache on localhost:80. The page contains AJAX code to get some JSONP back from localhost:8080/cocoon/test/

When I load localhost:8080/cocoon/test/ directly, I get the expected data:

```
{"titles":[
  {"title":"Title 1"}, 
  {"title":"Title 2"}, 
   ... , 
  {"title":"Title 999"}
]}
```

But when I execute the following:

```
function getTitles() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/cocoon/test/";
   $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

I get:

*"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:8080/cocoon/test/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."*

Does anyone know why the AJAX code above works with a Yahoo! url ( below ), but not with cocoon on localhost?

Thanks for any thoughts / guidance on this.

Yahoo!: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20name%20from%20geo.states%20where%20place%3D%22United%20States%22%20%7C%20sort(field%3D%22content%22)%20&format=json

Comment: directory set to `777`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The .xsl that builds the JSONP is in cocoon/test/xsl, so I just made the xsl dir 777 - same error.

Comment: The /test dir actually isn't in the cocoon dir; it's in another dir that the Tomcat/webapps/cocoon.war file is looking in for /test. I just made /test 777 - same error.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while, but I solved the CORS issue.

If you're serving from Apache HTTP Server, add the following to your httpd.conf file:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

If you're serving from Tomcat, add the following to your web.xml file:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```